# Read emnist database in C#

Tags: c#, mnist

I have an issue that I need help with. I need to read in the EMNIST database but can't get around to how to do it. The code works for the MNIST database but does not work for the EMNIST database even though they are supposed to be in the same binary format. Can any one please help me?

Code example for reading in the image data

```
if (_bImageFileOpen == false)
            { 
                byte[] m_byte = new byte[4];
                var openFileDialog1 = new System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog();
                openFileDialog1.Filter = "Mnist Image file (*.idx3-ubyte)|*.idx3-ubyte";
                openFileDialog1.Title = "Open Minist Image File";
                if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    _MnistImageFileName = openFileDialog1.FileName;

                    try
                    {
                        load_ImageFile_stream = new System.IO.BinaryReader(openFileDialog1.OpenFile());
                        //Magic number 
                        load_ImageFile_stream.Read(m_byte, 0, 4);
                        Array.Reverse(m_byte, 0, 4);
                        _ImageFileBegin.nMagic = BitConverter.ToInt32(m_byte, 0);
                        //number of images 
                        load_ImageFile_stream.Read(m_byte, 0, 4);
                        //High-Endian format to Low-Endian format
                        Array.Reverse(m_byte, 0, 4);
                        _ImageFileBegin.nItems = BitConverter.ToInt32(m_byte, 0);
                        _nItems = (uint)_ImageFileBegin.nItems;
                        //number of rows 
                        load_ImageFile_stream.Read(m_byte, 0, 4);
                        Array.Reverse(m_byte, 0, 4);
                        _ImageFileBegin.nRows = BitConverter.ToInt32(m_byte, 0);
                        //number of columns 
                        load_ImageFile_stream.Read(m_byte, 0, 4);
                        Array.Reverse(m_byte, 0, 4);
                        _ImageFileBegin.nCols = BitConverter.ToInt32(m_byte, 0);
                        _bImageFileOpen = true;
                        return true;
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        _bImageFileOpen = false;
                        return false;
                    }

                }
                return false;   

            }
            return true;
```

Answer (score 1):

I am able to read both MNIST and EMNIST with the following code:

```
string imagesPath = @"C:\Path\To\Images";
string labelsPath = @"C:\Path\To\Labels";
using (BinaryReader brImages = new BinaryReader(new FileStream(imagesPath, FileMode.Open)), brLabels = new BinaryReader(new FileStream(labelsPath, FileMode.Open)))
{
    int magic1 = brImages.ReadInt32Endian();
    if (magic1 != 2051)
        throw new Exception($"Invalid magic number {magic1}!");
    int numImages = brImages.ReadInt32Endian();
    int numRows = brImages.ReadInt32Endian();
    int numCols = brImages.ReadInt32Endian();

    Console.WriteLine($"Loading {numImages} images with {numRows} rows and {numCols} columns...");

    int magic2 = brLabels.ReadInt32Endian();
    if (magic2 != 2049)
        throw new Exception($"Invalid magic number {magic2}!");
    int numLabels = brLabels.ReadInt32Endian();
    if (numLabels != numImages)
        throw new Exception($"Number of labels ({numLabels}) does not equal number of images ({numImages})");

    byte[][] images = new byte[numImages][];
    byte[] labels = new byte[numLabels];
    int dimensions = numRows * numCols;
    for (int i = 0; i < numImages; i++)
    {
        images[i] = brImages.ReadBytes(dimensions);
        labels[i] = brLabels.ReadByte();
    }
}
```

I use the following extension to BinaryReader to correct endianness:

```
static class BinaryReaderExtension
{
    public static int ReadInt32Endian(this BinaryReader br)
    {
        var bytes = br.ReadBytes(sizeof(Int32));
        if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
            Array.Reverse(bytes);
        return BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi! Do you have a working example of it? `dimensions` is size of 28x28?

Comment: @michasaucer This *is* a working example. `dimensions` is read from the images file

Comment: In what format does this output the data in? How do I get Bitmaps from EMNIST data?